# What is the Shini kingdom?

Tags: harivamsa, kings

As I said in this [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31849/what-is-jarasandhas-military-force-according-to-boris-harivamsa), there is a kingdom called "Shini" that helped Jarasandha according to Harivamsa.

I want to know what this kingdom is, or if there was simply a translation error to refer to a king as "the king of Shini."

Answer (score 1):

The Shini Kingdom is most likely referring to the descendants of Śini, thier founder and who in turn is a descendant (grandson) of Vṛṣṇi. According to F. E. Pargiter in *Ancient Indian Historical Tradition*, pg.106:

> Vṛṣṇi's youngest son Anamitra had a son Śini, and their descendants
>   were called the Śainyas. All these are shown in the table opposite.

Here's the said table from the book showing the descendants of Vṛṣṇi, albeit a little confusing and may be inaccurate, since several other sources describe Vṛṣṇi's descendants a little differently:

[image]

As you can see, Lord Krishna and Balarama are also descendants of Vṛṣṇi. In the Bhagavad Gita, Arjuna refers to Lord Krishna as such.

You can access the book directly here: https://archive.org/details/ancientindianhis00parguoft/page/106

Comment: But that becomes confusing because Satyaki was fighting for Dwarka, besides that 10 sons of Satyaki fought in Kurukshetra (what happened several years after the death of Jarasandha).

Comment: @GabrielAlexanderGonzalezAgu maybe this answer can be of some help: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27492/what-is-the-story-of-satyaki

Comment: I had already read that answer, possibly only was named as his only son to Jaya because he was his heir or because they were not given the names of his 10 children who participated in Kurukshetra